# DNA Computing Algorithm to solve the Hamiltonian problem

Tags: complexity-theory

Is it possible to represent the [algorithm proposed by Adleman](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computador_de_DNA#A_solu.C3.A7.C3.A3o_do_problema) to solve the Hamiltonian problem in a probabilistic Turing Machine?

See also [Computing with DNA](http://www.usc.edu/dept/molecular-science/papers/fp-sciam98.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course.  The Hamiltonian path problem is decidable, so it can be solved using a Turing machine.

I recommend you read about the Church-Turing hypothesis, decidability, and undecidability.  I think you'll find those topics of interest.

Comment: think maybe hes asking if the Adleman algorithm can be implemented in a probabilistic TM

Comment: yes @vzn, my question is: Can the Adleman algorithm be implemented in a probabilistic TM?